# New to C++, having trouble understanding nuances of the language

Tags: c++

I've been coding in swift and python for a while, but I've been wanting to learn C++ and have been doing these daily challenges. This challenge in specific requires you to take a string, and then split each letter into an element for an array. I can do that fairly easily, but the language seems to have gotten the better of me.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::string> solution(const std::string &s)
{ 
return {}; // Your code here
}
```

I am super confused by that third line. I have no idea where I'm supposed to take the input from and what means what. If someone could break down that entire third line for me that would be hugely appreciated. Thank you a ton in advance.

Comment: You have a function that takes a string and returns a vector of strings. It's up to you to provide the logic to do that. I recommend you consult a basic C++ textbook.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` is a vector of the strings (in your case it will be letters) that you will return as output from the function, `solution` is the name of the function, `const std::string &s` is a input sthing that you need to split in this task. `const` means that you cannot change it

Comment: The input is the parameter `s`.

Comment: If those "daily challenges" just throw new language features at you without explaining what they are, they'll probably not the best way to learn the language, at least at this level. Consider reading a good C++ book/tutorial first.

Answer (score 2):

The third line is `std::vector<std::string> solution(const std::string &s)`. It declares a function in C++. The declaration has three parts: return type, function name and parameters name and type. So `std::vector<std::string>` is the return type, `solution` is the function name and `(const std::string &s)` is the paramer
list.

First of all, `std` is a namespace in C++. A namespace can isolate functions so even if two function signatures are the same, as long as they live in different namespaces they can be distinguished as two functions. To use something ins a namespace `::` operator will help. `std::vector` is a container type in C++. It is a growable array, much like `NSArray` in swift. `std::vector` is actually a C++ template which adds generics to the language (but can do a lot more).`<std::string>` is the type parameter, which is used to tell the compiler what type of objects will be stored in the vector.

Then in the parameter list, `const` is the abbreviation for constant, which means you cannot modify the content of the parameter in the function. `std::string` denotes the type of the parameter. Unlike swift, C++ puts the type of a variable before it but not after it with a colon. and lastly `&s` is the name of the parameter. Here `&` means a reference. Since C++ passes values instead of references to the function by default, to reduce the runtime overhead in passing a large object many parameters will be denoted as to pass a reference to it.

These should be the basic knowledge to write a C++ program, so I recommend you to first read some books about C++ to learn more on this

Comment: minor nitpick: the name of the parameter is `s`, the `&` is part of its type

Answer (score 0):

It's a function that returns vector of strings and takes const reference to the string value. Take a look at lvalue and rvalue, what does const means and vector container (it takes template parameter).

Comment: he does not need to learn about lvalues and rvalues to understand the code and solve his problem.